# Einstein equations from the Palatini action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

I am trying to obtain the usual form of vacuum Einstein's equations

$$ R_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu \nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu \nu} = 0 $$

from the first-order (Palatini) tetradic action

$$ S[\underline{e}, \underline{\omega}] = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\int_{M}\epsilon_{IJKL}\underline{e}^{I}\wedge\underline{e}^{J}\wedge\left(\underline{\underline{R}}[\omega]^{KL}+\frac{\Lambda}{2}\cdot\underline{e}^{K}\wedge\underline{e}^{L}\right). $$

Here $\underline{e}^I(x) = e_{\mu}^{\;I}(x) \, dx^{\mu}$ is the tetrad 1-form field (frame, vierbein, choose your pick) and $\underline{\omega} ^{I} _{\;J} (x) = \omega ^{\;I} _{\mu\;\;J} (x) \, dx^{\mu}$ is the spin connection 1-form field. I put $n$ lines underneath an $n$-form to be able to track the ranks of all forms in my equations.

Variating the action with respect to the spin connection gives the frame-connection compatibility equation. That part I have successfully reproduced.

Now I variate the action with respect to the frame:

$$ \delta S=\frac{1}{16\pi G}\times\int_{M}\epsilon_{IJKL}\left(\underline{\delta e}^{I}\wedge\underline{e}^{J}\wedge\underline{\underline{R}}[\omega]^{KL}+\underline{e}^{I}\wedge\underline{\delta e}^{J}\wedge\underline{\underline{R}}[\omega]^{KL}+\frac{\Lambda}{2}\cdot\delta\left[\underline{e}^{I}\wedge\underline{e}^{J}\wedge\underline{e}^{K}\wedge\underline{e}^{L}\right]\right) $$
$$ =\frac{1}{16\pi G}\int_{M}\epsilon_{IJKL}\left(2\underline{\delta e}^{I}\wedge\underline{e}^{J}\wedge\underline{\underline{R}}[\omega]^{KL}+2\Lambda\cdot\delta\underline{e}^{I}\wedge\underline{e}^{J}\wedge\underline{e}^{K}\wedge\underline{e}^{L}\right)=0. $$
$$ \epsilon_{IJKL}\left(\underline{e}^{J}\wedge\underline{\underline{R}}[\omega]^{KL}+\Lambda\cdot\underline{e}^{J}\wedge\underline{e}^{K}\wedge\underline{e}^{L}\right)=0. $$

This actually is the correct form of the Einstein's equtions in the Cartan formalism (I compared them to the calculations given in Rovelli's book on quantum gravity).

Now I want to show that this form of equations is equivalent to the usual form (the first equation in this post), and at this point I am stuck.

The usual definition of the Ricci tensor in Cartan formalism is

$$ R ^I _{\mu} = R^{IJ}_{\mu \nu} e^{\nu} _J. $$

I would appreciate an advice, but I want to carry out the calculations on my own.

Comment: Here are two hints: (1) expand out the wedge products in terms of indices using the epsilon tensor, (2) you can use the fact that (up to a possible sign and/or combinatoric factor) $\epsilon_{abcd} =(|e|) \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} e_a^\mu e_b^\nu e_c^\rho e_d^\sigma$ where $|e|=\sqrt{-g}$ is the determinant of the vielbein and $e^\mu_a$ is the inverse vielbein. Then you should be left with contractions of epsilon tensors and geometric quantities with only spacetime ($\mu,\nu$) indices which you can evaluate.

Comment: $$\epsilon_{IJKL}\left({e}^{J}_\beta \frac 1 2 {{R}}[\omega]^{KL}_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda\cdot{e}^{J}_\beta{e}^{K}_\mu{e}^{L}_\nu\right)dx^\beta \wedge dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu=0,\\ \longrightarrow \epsilon_{IJKL}\left({e}^{J}_\beta \frac 1 2 {{R}}[\omega]^{KL}_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda\cdot{e}^{J}_\beta{e}^{K}_\mu{e}^{L}_\nu\right)dx^\alpha \wedge dx^\beta \wedge dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu=0\\\epsilon_{IJKL}\left({e}^{J}_\beta \frac 1 2 {{R}}[\omega]^{KL}_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda\cdot{e}^{J}_\beta{e}^{K}_\mu{e}^{L}_\nu\right)\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}=0 $$ You then can continue to solve.

Comment: In the action it must be $$\left(\underline{\underline{R}}[\omega]^{KL}-\frac{\Lambda}{6}\cdot\underline{e}^{K}\wedge\underline{e}^{L}\right)$$